# Unable to get any Contacts from the Outlook REST API?

Tags: php, outlook, outlook-restapi

**Problem**
I am trying to get all the contacts of the person that logs in. Problem is though that it won't work. I am using a GitHub project which is used as a tutorial by Outlook. When I start up the project and log in, the project returns null. It wont even show me the HTML Table Headers. I know for sure that I correctly registered the application and am using the right appId and appSecret. And yes i have contacts in the account I am using to test. I manually added a few.

tl;dr
So basically Html wont show and `var_dump($contacts)` returns NULL.

**Question**
How can I make my Html show and make my application get Contacts from my outlook account.

**Links**
GitHub Project: https://github.com/jasonjoh/php-tutorial 
Outlook Tutorial: https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/php

I only use Contacts.php which is my startpage, Outlook.php, authorize.php, oauth.php

I know I am not showing any code, but thats because its a bit much to put in a question and I dont know where the problem lies.

Comment: Unless you post your code and/or the errors being thrown, there is no way for the community to help you.

Comment: I am not getting any errors only a warning that headers have already been sent.

Comment: If you could get a network trace showing the REST calls that might be helpful. You might also verify that your Outlook account is enabled for the APIs by going to https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/, logging in with the account, then trying to do a Contacts API call.